# Function to iterate over an array of dates produces unexpected results

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, momentjs

I have a CloudCode function that is called from my iOS app. The function is supposed to create a "checkin" record and return a string to represent the last 30 days of check-ins and missed days.

The strange thing is that sometimes I get the expected results and sometimes I do not. It makes me think that there is some issue with the may I am using timezones - since that could result in a different set of "days in the past" depending on what time I run this function and what time of day I checked-in in the past. But I'm baffled and could use some help here.

It's also confusing me that I do not see all of my console.log() results appear in the parse log. Is that normal?? For example, in the for loop, I can uncomment the console.log entry and call the function but I will not see all of the days in the past listed - but they are included in the final array and text string.

Here is my complete function. Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

```
/* Function for recording a daily check in
 *
 * Calculates the number of days missed and updates the string used to display the check-in pattern.
 * If no days missed then we increment the current count
 *
 * Input:
 * "promiseId" : objectID,
 * "timeZoneDifference" : String +07:00
 *
 * Output:
 * JSON String  eg. {"count":6,"string":"000000000000001111101010111111"}
 *
 */
Parse.Cloud.define("dailyCheckIn", function(request, response) {
    var promiseId = request.params.promiseId;
    var timeZoneDifference = request.params.timeZoneDifference;    
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

    if (currentUser === undefined) {
        response.error("You must be logged in.");
    }

    if (timeZoneDifference === undefined || timeZoneDifference === "") {
        //console.log("timeZoneDifference missing. Set to -07:00");
        timeZoneDifference = '' + '-07:00'; // PacificTime as string
    }

    var moment = require('cloud/libs/moment.js');

    // Query for the Promise
    var Promise = Parse.Object.extend("Promise");
    var queryforPromise = new Parse.Query(Promise);

    queryforPromise.get(promiseId, {
        success: function(promis) {

            // Initialize
            var dinarowString = "";
            var dinarowCount = 0;

            // Last Check In date from database (UTC)
            var lastCheckInUTC = promis.get("lastCheckIn");
            if (lastCheckInUTC === undefined) {
                lastCheckInUTC = new Date(2015, 1, 1);
            }

            // Use moment() to convert lastCheckInUTC to local timezone
            var lastCheckInLocalized = moment(lastCheckInUTC.toString()).utcOffset(timeZoneDifference);
                //console.log('lastCheckIn: ' + lastCheckInUTC.toString());
                //console.log('lastCheckInLocalized: ' + lastCheckInLocalized.format());

            // Use moment() to get "now" in UTC timezone
            var today = moment().utc(); // new Date(); 
                //console.log('today: ' + today.format());

            // Use moment() to get "now" in local timezone
            var todayLocalized = today.utcOffset(timeZoneDifference);
                //console.log('todayLocalized: ' + todayLocalized.format());

            // 30 days in the past
            var thirtydaysago = moment().utc().subtract(30, 'days');
                //console.log("thirtydaysago = " + thirtydaysago.format());

            // 30 days in the past in local timezone
            var thirtydaysagoLocalized = thirtydaysago.utcOffset(timeZoneDifference);
                //console.log('thirtydaysagoLocalized: ' + thirtydaysagoLocalized.format());

            // Calculate the number of days since last time user checked in
            var dayssincelastcheckin = todayLocalized.diff(lastCheckInLocalized, 'days');
                //console.log("Last check-in was " + dayssincelastcheckin + " days ago");

            // Function takes an array of Parse.Objects of type Checkin
            // itterate over the array to get a an array of days in the past as numnber
            // generate a string of 1 and 0 for the past 30 days where 1 is a day user checked in
            function dinarowStringFromCheckins(checkins) {
                var days_array = [];
                var dinarowstring = "";

                // Create an array entry for every day that we checked in (daysago)
                for (var i = 0; i < checkins.length; i++) {
                    var checkinDaylocalized = moment(checkins[i].get("checkInDate")).utcOffset(timeZoneDifference);
                    var daysago = todayLocalized.diff(checkinDaylocalized, 'days');
                    // console.log("daysago = " + daysago);
                    days_array.push(daysago);
                }
                console.log("days_array = " + days_array);

                // Build the string with 30 day of hits "1" and misses "0" with today on the right
                for (var c = 29; c >= 0; c--) {
                    if (days_array.indexOf(c) != -1) {
                        //console.log("days ago (c) = " + c + "-> match found");
                        dinarowstring += "1";
                    } else {
                        dinarowstring += "0";
                    }
                }
                return dinarowstring;
            }

            // Define ACL for new Checkin object
            var checkinACL = new Parse.ACL();
            checkinACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
            checkinACL.setReadAccess(currentUser, true);
            checkinACL.setWriteAccess(currentUser, true);

            // Create a new entry in the Checkin table
            var Checkin = Parse.Object.extend("Checkin");
            var checkin = new Checkin();
            checkin.set("User", currentUser);
            checkin.set("refPromise", promis);
            checkin.set("checkInDate", today.toDate());
            checkin.setACL(checkinACL);
            checkin.save().then(function() {
                // Query Checkins
                var Checkin = Parse.Object.extend("Checkin");
                var queryforCheckin = new Parse.Query(Checkin);
                queryforCheckin.equalTo("refPromise", promis);
                queryforCheckin.greaterThanOrEqualTo("checkInDate", thirtydaysago.toDate());
                queryforCheckin.descending("checkInDate");
                queryforCheckin.find().then(function(results) {
                    var dinarowString = "000000000000000000000000000000";
                    var dinarowCount = 0;
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        dinarowString = dinarowStringFromCheckins(results);
                        dinarowIndex = dinarowString.lastIndexOf("0");
                        if (dinarowIndex === -1) { // Checked in every day in the month!
                            // TODO
                            // If the user has checked in every day this month then we need to calculate the 
                            // correct streak count in a different way 
                            dinarowString = "111111111111111111111111111111";
                            dinarowCount = 999;
                        } else {
                            dinarowCount = 29 - dinarowIndex;
                        }
                    }
                    // Update the promise with new value and save
                    promis.set("dinarowString", dinarowString);
                    promis.set("dinarowCount", dinarowCount);
                    promis.set("lastCheckIn", today.toDate());
                    promis.save().then(function() {
                        response.success(JSON.stringify({
                            count: dinarowCount,
                            string: dinarowString
                        }));
                    });
                }, function(reason) {
                    console.log("Checkin query unsuccessful:" + reason.code + " " + reason.message);
                    response.error("Something went wrong");
                });

            }); // save.then
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            console.error("dailyCheckIn failed: " + error);
            response.error("Unable to check-in. Try again later.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You'll  need to include examples of when you're getting expected results and when you're not, as well as why those are expected or not.  Also would probably be helpful to peruse this -http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The key in [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is *minimal*.  This looks like an entire program.

Comment: You also need to completely forget local timezone and use only UTC until it's time to display a time and date. Input date and times should be converted to UTC immediately.

Comment: @RobG - Actually, adding/subtracting days is one case where that is not true.  A UTC day is always 24 hours, but a local day may be more or less due to DST transitions.  If by "day" one means the local day, then you can't use UTC or a fixed offset.  You have to convert to the local time zone first, and use tz-aware add/subtract methods. (moment's are, when in local or tz modes).

Comment: @MattJohnson—what "adding a day" across a daylight saving boundary means is dependant on administrative rules, such as whether the source system observes daylight saving, there is no one rule for all cases. Adding a day to a date may be handled differently to adding 24 hours to a time. I have no idea what "local or tz  modes" means.

Comment: I do need to use localized dates when calculating "days ago". If I check in at 2am "today" and have previously checked in at 11pm "yesterday" then both of those times are in the same "day" in UTC - but they are two different days in PDT. 

That's the root of my problem here. I am seeing different results depending on when I check in. So my assertion is that I am using moment() incorrectly or converting to local TZ incorrectly at some point in my code. I know it was a lot to ask but I'm basically asking for a code review. I appreciate everyone's feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I have found the solution.

I had two questions. The first was "why do I get unexpected (incorrect) results" and I suspected that it was related to the way I am using timezones. I would see different results from day to day depending on what time I check in.

The problem is actually related to the way that moment().diff() works. Diff does not calculate "days" the way I expected it to. If I compare 2am today with 11pm yesterday diff will say 0 days because it is less than 24 hours diff. If I compare 1am on Thursday with 8pm on the previous Monday, diff will report 2 days - not 3 as I expected. It's a precision issue. Diff thinks 2.4 days is 2 days ago. But it is more than 2 therefor it is 3 days ago.

We found that the easiest solution is to compare the two dates at midnight rather than at the actual time of day that is recorded in the database. This yields correct results for days. The rest of the code is working fine.

```
            //Find start time of today's day
            var todayLocalizedStart = todayLocalized.startOf('day');

            for (var i = 0; i < checkins.length; i++) {
                var checkinDaylocalized = moment(checkins[i].get("checkInDate")).utcOffset(timeZoneDifference);

                //Find start time of checkIn day
                var checkinDaylocalizedStart = checkinDaylocalized.startOf('day');

                //Find number of days
                var daysago = todayLocalizedStart.diff(checkinDaylocalizedStart, 'days');
                // console.log("daysago = " + daysago);

                days_array.push(daysago);
            }
```

The second question I had was "is it normal to not see every console.log at runtime". I've talked with other Parse.com users and they report that Parse is inconsistent in logging. I was spending a lot of time debugging "problems" that were simply Parse not logging correctly.

Thanks to everyone that contributed to the answer.

I did make one other change - but it was not a bug. I replaced the query limit from 30 days in the past to simply "30". It's just a bit simpler with one less calculation.

Answer (score 2):

There's too much going on in your question to answer adequately, but I will be nice and at least point out a few errors that you should look into:

1. You take input in terms of a fixed offset, but then you are doing operations that subtract 30 days.  It's entirely possible that you will cross a daylight saving time boundary, in which case the offset will have changed.

   See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  In moment, you can use time zones names like `"America/Los_Angeles"` with the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on.

   From your example, I'm not even sure if time zone even matters or not for your use case.
2. You should not convert the `Date` to a string just to parse it again.  Moment can accept a `Date` object, assuming the `Date` object was created correctly.

   ```
   moment(lastCheckInUTC.toString()).utcOffset(timeZoneDifference)
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   moment(lastCheckInUTC).utcOffset(timeZoneDifference)
   ```

   Since `Date.toString()` returns a locale-specific, implementation-specific format, you'll also see you have a warning in the debug console from moment.

As for the rest, we can't run your program and reproduce the results, so there's not much we can do to help.  You need to start by debugging your own program, and then try to reproduce your error in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Chances are, you'll solve your own problem along the way.  If not, then you will have something in a better state to share with us.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. 

Regarding 1) The 30 days is simply use to limit the results to the smallest required set. I could have said return max 30 results - even though that is likely to return results that are older than 30 days, it's much simpler. I think that's what I'll do. 

2) I have used it both ways - with and without the .toString(). Thank you for confirming that toString() is not required and not desirable. Since the problem I am having is very odd I was grasping at anything that might make a difference. 

I'll continue to debug and post more focused questions.

Comment: Thanks again Matt. I just re-read your response regarding using timezone offset. I now get your point about static offsets can be incorrect if you go back 30 days and we are no longer in Daylight savings time. (for example).